# Change() inside each() jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-handling

What is the best way to manage this kind of situation :

```
$('.element').each(function() {

    $sibling = // find a sibling to $this.
    $mainElement = $(this); // memorize $(this)
    $sibling.change(function() {
       // when sibling changes
       // do something using $mainElement
       // problem is, $mainElement is not the element you think
       // $mainElement is the last .element found....
    })
});
```

One solution would be a table... But then there is no advantage for the change() to be nested in the each()...

My html example :

```
<div id="first">
  <span class="element"></span>
  <input name="first" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="second">
  <span class="element"></span>
  <input name="second" type="text" />
</div>
```

In this exemple, `$sibling = $(this).next('input');` for instance.

Comment: Have you tried: var  $sibling = // find a sibling to $this.
   var  $mainElement = $(this);

Comment: Posted html, sorry for the wait.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do it, is to use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/165154). This will *capture* the variable in `$mainElement`, so to speak, using its current value.

```
$('.element').each(function() {

    $sibling = // find a sibling to $this.
    $mainElement = $(this); // memorize $(this)
    $sibling.change(function($mainElement) {
        return function() {
            // use $mainElement
        }
    }($mainElement))
});
```

[*jsfiddle example*](http://jsfiddle.net/WCDBr/) (be sure to blur the textfield, after editing, otherwise `.change()` won't fire)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I looked for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.element .sibling').each(function( ind, el) {

    $parent = $( el ).closest( '.element' );
    $( el ).change(function() {
         $parent.doSomething();
    });

});
```

Comment: This seems another proper solution. Would you rather do this than a closure and why?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$('.element').each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.sibling').change(function() {
       var mainElement = $(this).siblings('.element');
        // Play here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest bet for you is to use an .each on the siblings, and then finding the relative ".element" for the sibling. Depends on your code of course. Otherwise, something like this might work, even though it feels a bit redundant due to the .each:

```
$('.element').each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.sibling').change(function() {
        var mainElement = $(this).siblings('.element');
        // Do whatever you want here...
    });
});
```