# removeClass("has-error") when field was changed Bootstrap, javascript

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

#### My Javascript

```
$('.input-group').each(function() {
$mainElement = $(this);
$sibling = $mainElement.next('.form-control');
$sibling.change(function($mainElement) {
    return function() {
        $mainElement.removeClass('has-error');        
    }
}($mainElement)); });
```

#### My Form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Organization</label>
    <div class="input-group has-error">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="organization" />
        <!--added code-->
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Address</label>
    <div class="input-group has-error">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" />
        <!--added code-->
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea came from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WCDBr/) after I try one of `.each()` solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910100/change-inside-each-jquery)

I used twitter bootstrap for this for showing `.has-error` class after PHP back-end validation which I PREFERRED. Now I want to remove `.each()`  `.has-error` classes for any changes happened in those `.form-control` under those `.input-group`.

Take note... I do not want to use the jQuery validation here.

Someone provided the BEST ANSWER here with a link below:

https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/324/remove-class-haserror-when-field-was-changed

and I revised it like this:

```
$('.input-group').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.form-control').change(function(){
        $(this).closest('div').removeClass('has-error');            
    });
});
```

now as I revised my code, I added the:

```
$('.input-group').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.form-control').change(function(){
        $(this).closest('div').removeClass('has-error').closest('span').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');            
    });
});
```

within the  and same thing I want to remove the glyphicon-remove class like the has-error class once the .form-control field have changed.

I played the code but still the glyphicon-remove class is still there.

Comment: So you want to remove `.has-error` class? `$('.has-error').removeClass('.has-error');`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do: just remove the .has-error class from the parent of the changed `<input>`?

`$('.input-group .form-control').change( function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply attach an event if element has the class

[**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/324/remove-class-haserror-when-field-was-changed)

```
$(function(){
    $('div.input-group.has-error').each(function(){
        $(this).find('input').change(function(){
            $(this).closest('div').removeClass('has-error');   
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The closest div might not be the one containing `has-error`.

Comment: so - `closest('div.has-error')` or `closest('.has-error')`

Comment: thank you for this...
I almost used to think that I can use the closest() things around there but didnt step forward like that...
I revised your code by removing the .has-error class and still working fine...

$(function(){
    $('div.input-group').each(function(){
        $(this).find('input').change(function(){
            $(this).closest('div').removeClass('has-error');   
        });
    });
});

Comment: @EmersonMatiasPaguia the reason I put the `has-error` class is to add the handler only to the error elements - Its cleaner and avoid unneeded handlers. But both will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes:

```
$('.form-control').find('input[type="text"]').on('input', function() {
     $(this).closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error');        
});
```

1. Instead of `change` event use `keydown` on the input type text as change event happens only when you loose the focus from the element.
2. get in the context with `$(this)` get up to the desired parent with `.closest()` and just remove the class from it.

```js
$(':input').on('input', function(e){
    console.log('type', e.type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' >
```

Comment: `keydown` doesn't monitor `Right-click > Paste`

Comment: @rybo111 that is where `.on()` method is useful to bind the multiple events on a single selector. see the update.

Comment: `keydown paste input` will run the function twice on paste.

Comment: That depends how the elements are created and OP has not mentioned that and as per your last comment `input` will only be option to choose. and for dynamically created elements event can be delegated to the closest static parent like the wrapper of the element whether a div or to document/body itself.

Comment: Even if the OP doesn't use dynamic inputs now (which we don't know), he might later. If you can support them, might as well.

Comment: By the way, there is no need for `.find()` here. You can use `$('.form-control input[type="text"]')`

Comment: The alternative to `find()` seems instantaneous but if you have any data on `.find()` being quicker I'd be keen to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).on('input'...` to monitor all changes to dynamic and static elements:

```
$(document).on('input', '.form-control', function(){
  $(this).closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error');
});
```